# Split a polygons into many polygons based on points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, splitting, voronoi-thiessen

I have:

1. A polygon feature that is a national park boundary,
2. A multi-point feature that are security guard posts (number = *n* ) of the same park.

I want to divide the national park area into '*n*' polygons such that each polygon represents the command area of a security guard post. The areas can vary.

How do I do this in ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: If you have an Advanced license, you can use [Create Thiessen Polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001m000000)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Create Thiessen Polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001m000000) Tool for this. This will build polygons around each security guard post (your point layer) where every place within each polygon is closer to its associated guard post than any other guard post.

The polygons will be created for the entire extent of your points layer +10% (default extent of the tool). You can then use the [Clip tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000), using the National Park boundary polygon as your "cookie cutter", to create a new layer with just the National Park shown.